# PGFplots: asin(deg(x)) - dimension too large

Tags: pgfplots

I have a problem with pgfplots. I have no clue why asin(deg(x)) gives me a Dimension too large error. Can u help? I couldn't find any solution, so that's why I'm asking. Here's the code.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{color}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
          xmax=2,xmin=-2,
          ymax=2,ymin=-2,
          xlabel=x,ylabel=y,
          xtick={-1.57, 1.57}, xticklabels={$-\pi$/2,$\pi$/2},
          ytick={-1.57, 1.57}, yticklabels={$-\pi$/2,$\pi$/2},
          axis lines=middle,
          axis equal, 
          legend style={at={(1.3,0.5)},anchor=center}
          ]
    \addplot[blue,domain=-pi/2:pi/2, samples=50] {sin(deg(x))};
    \addplot[red,domain=-1:1,samples=100]  {asin(deg(x))};
    \addplot[gray, dashed, domain=-1.7:1.7]  {x};
    \addlegendentry{$y = \sin x$}
    \addlegendentry{$y = \arcsin x$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The inverse sine function has domain -1:1, I think you're trying to input values outside of it

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. Ideally it should compile  unless, of course, that is what you are asking about.

Comment: Not sure if `asin(deg(x))` will work the way you intend. `asin(t)` would only be defined for a domain of `-1<=t<=1`, wouldn't it?

Comment: why are you converting `x`? Angle is the result of asin not the argument

Comment: Actually, the arcsin D(f) is [-1,1], that's what I'm inserting. I added the preamble for Andrew. If I use asin(x) only, it makes just a line from top to bottom.

Answer (score 5):

`asin` gives a result in degrees, so you need `rad(asin(x))` to convert it to radians, as that is what you're plotting.

[image: output of image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
          xmax=2,xmin=-2,
          ymax=2,ymin=-2,
          xlabel=x,ylabel=y,
          xtick={-1.57, 1.57}, xticklabels={$-\pi$/2,$\pi$/2},
          ytick={-1.57, 1.57}, yticklabels={$-\pi$/2,$\pi$/2},
          axis lines=middle,
          axis equal, 
          legend style={at={(1.3,0.5)},anchor=center}
          ]
    \addplot[blue,domain=-pi/2:pi/2, samples=50] {sin(deg(x))};
    \addplot[red,domain=-1:1,samples=100]  {rad(asin(x))};
    \addplot[gray, dashed, domain=-1.7:1.7]  {x};
    \addlegendentry{$y = \sin x$}
    \addlegendentry{$y = \arcsin x$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes! That's it! Thank you very very very much! :D You saved my mental health... I was about to go bananas. :D